# How do I use the Tactical Enhancement pack I redeemed in Deus Ex?

Tags: ps3, deus-ex-human-revolution

I successfully redeemed my tactical enhancement pack pre-order bonus on my PS3, but I dont see the weapons in my inventory.  I'm currently roaming the city after the first mission at Sarif and I can't figure when they (and the money that was supposed to come with the pack) become available.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

According to [this thread](http://www.gamespot.com/xbox360/action/deus-ex-human-revolution/show_msgs.php?pid=944089&topic_id=m-1-60178118) the bonus is added right after your brief with Sarif on the flight to the manufacturing plant mission.  If you activated the code after that point, then you will not receive the bonus.

Comment: yes.  I was 3+ hours in.  Restarted the game.  I also wanted that 10k credits to buy two Praxis with.  It worked, the tactical pack showed up as I was being choppered into Sarif w/ David

Comment: So, if I've passed those parts, I missed out on the Credits? Bummer. That actually kind of sucks.

Answer (score 2):

The new weapons also show up at the regular gun vendors. I'm not sure which vendors get which weapons, but I found both the Silenced Sniper Rifle and the Double Barrel Shotgun at different vendors in China.

Answer (score 0):

As a matter of fact, I was just playing yesterday, I opened the storage room by the basketball court that requires Level 5 Hacking and saw the silenced sniper rifle in there. In China, there is a vendor that sells the double barrel shotgun.